# Any Idea why this calculator Console-Application does not work?

Tags: c#, console-application, calculator, unhandled-exception

So I've been developing my ideas about how to write a calculator and I keep on getting an unhandled exception every time but the code does not present any errors, and after reading through the code multiple times I'm not certain what is going wrong.

```
string inp;
int location;
double num1, num2, ans;
string[] ops = {"+", "-", "*", "/" };

Console.WriteLine("Calculator");
Console.WriteLine("Enter a Calculation.");
inp = Console.ReadLine();

if (inp.Contains(ops[0])) 
{
    location = inp.IndexOf("+");
    num1 = double.Parse(inp.Substring(0, location));
    num2 = double.Parse(inp.Substring(location +1));
    ans = num1 + num2;
    Console.WriteLine("{0}+{2}={3}", num1, num2, ans.ToString("0.###"));
}
else if (inp.Contains(ops[1]))
{
    location = inp.IndexOf("-");
    num1 = double.Parse(inp.Substring(0, location));
    num2 = double.Parse(inp.Substring(location +1));
    ans = num1 - num2;
    Console.WriteLine("{0}-{2}={3}", num1, num2, ans.ToString("0.###"));
}
else if (inp.Contains(ops[2])) 
{
    location = inp.IndexOf("*");
    num1 = double.Parse(inp.Substring(0, location));
    num2 = double.Parse(inp.Substring(location +1));
    ans = num1 * num2;
    Console.WriteLine("{0}*{2}={3}", num1, num2, ans.ToString("0.###"));
}
else if (inp.Contains(ops[3]))
{
    location = inp.IndexOf("/");
    num1 = double.Parse(inp.Substring(0, location));
    num2 = double.Parse(inp.Substring(location +1));
    ans = num1 / num2;
    Console.WriteLine("{0}/{2}={3}", num1, num2, ans.ToString("0.###"));
}
```

Comment: Have you tried running it under the debugger?

Comment: Yes I have and nothing showed

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? What exception is being thrown? What line of code throws the exception? Also, attach a sample input, and the expected result

Comment: `unhandled exception` what exception? Also you might `Trim` the input `inp.Substring(0, location).Trim()` to remove spaces

Comment: In Visual Studio, go to *Debug | Windows | Exception Settings* and ensure that *Break When Thrown* is enabled for  *Common Language Runtime Exceptions*. Then run it under the debugger again.

Answer (score 5):

You see nothing because the code throws an exception and is getting finished without telling you anything but you could detect that if you debug the code ;)

> *the code does not present any errors*

the  code is free of compiling errors but your code is gerenating an error at runtime

You have an exception because of this line

```
Console.WriteLine("{0}+{2}={3}", num1, num2, ans.ToString("0.###"));
```

**{0}+{2}={3}** must be **{0}+{1}={2}**

as they are index in an array defined by

```
num1, num2, ans.ToString("0.###")
```

Answer (score 1):

your index order is wrong when you show result to user here:
**Console.WriteLine("{0}+{2}={3}", num1, num2, ans.ToString("0.###"));**

change your index number to 0, 1, 2... and goes to get your variables when you format a string.

Also this code does not work when user enters more than one operator like: 22+66+88

i updated your + operator part to avoid this. check this out.

```
        string inp;
        int location;
        double num1, num2, ans = 0.0;
        string[] ops = { "+", "-", "*", "/" };
        string[] numbers;
        string output;
        Console.WriteLine("Calculator");
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a Calculation.");
        inp = Console.ReadLine();

        if (inp.Contains(ops[0]))
        {
            numbers = inp.Split('+');
            output = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
            {
                ans += Convert.ToDouble(numbers[i]);
            }



            Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", inp, ans.ToString("0.###"));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Comment: Your answer is correct - but could you perhaps explain to the OP why, and how they can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

When writing out your result make sure to use the correct syntax when formatting your string.

```
Console.WriteLine("{0}+{1}={2}", num1, num2, ans.ToString("0.###"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Code is correct to compile. but it has some logical error-
First Need to change 
Console.WriteLine("{0}+{2}={3}", num1, num2, ans.ToString("0.###"))
To
Console.WriteLine("{0}+{1}={2}", num1, num2, ans.ToString("0.###"))
after this change, code will work for single expression like 2+8 or 3-8
For multicalculation change your logic to get 'num' value from calculation string.